# Angular model getter "is not a function" error

Tags: angular, function, model, google-cloud-firestore

My model:

```
export class User {

   public username: string;
   private email: string;

   constructor() {
       this.username = undefined;
       this.email = undefined;
   }

   public getUsername(): string {
       return this.username;
   }
```

In my view I have:

```
import {User} from '../../models/usermodel';

export classs ... {

   user: Observable<User | null>
   userCollection: AngularFirestoreCollection<User>;
   userLoadedFromFirestore: User[];

   this.userCollection = this.afs.collection('users', ref => ref.where('email', '==', this.sessionData.getUser().getEmail()));
   this.userCollection.valueChanges().subscribe((item => {
       this.userLoadedFromFirestore = item;
       this.userLoadedFromFirestore[0].getUsername();
```

For accessing `getUsername()` I get runtime error: `is not a function`. Why is that? When I do `this.userLoadedFromFirestore[0].username` instead, it works!

The IDE does not show any errors during compiling...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You set a type of userLoadedFromFirestore as a `User[]` type, but when data arrives, it doesn't guarantee that that object will be a `User` type. Thats why it is a good idea to set the type of incoming data:

`subscribe(((item: User[]) => {`

And in your case, most likely you need:

`this.userLoadedFromFirestore[0].username;`

Comment: after doing `subscribe(((item: User[]) => {` I still get the same error

Comment: yes, I mean it doesnt change the fact that the object comming from backend might not have the properties you defined in frontend. By defining types as I wrote, you just receive an error as soon as objects mismatch. Your `item` is not of type of `User[]`. Pleas explain you goal further as I it seams you want to create an instance of `User` with properties coming from database?

Comment: I would argue that setting parameter types on a method call is an anti-pattern. The return type should be implicitly set by the method returning the data, independent of its invokers (via the generic parameter <User>).

Comment: so you have a constructor function - instantiate new instance with `new` keyword - `new User` (also probably want to add some arguments to constructor function

Comment: @joh04667 but he didnt set parameter type on a method call. He just typed a variable (`userLoadedFromFirestore: User[];`) and later assign it a value of the incomming object with hope it will behave as an object of that type

Comment: never mind. Im just going with `this.userLoadedFromFirestore[0].username;`

Comment: yep, I just later noticed you already tried `this.userLoadedFromFirestore[0].username;` :)

Answer (score 0):

In my case the solution was to organize the getter outside of the object.

```
export class UserData {

    public gid: string;
    
    //Error!
    public gidText(): string{
        return this.gid;
    }

}
```

Solution:

```
export class UserService {

    public gidText(): string{
       return this.userData.gid;
    }

    export class UserData {
        public gid: string;
    }
}
```